# Require.js from command line mode

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Let's suppose I can access the following code:

```
http://localhost/web/src/js/myApp.js
```

Now I want to load `myApp.js` using requirejs from the javascript command line mode.

I did try the following but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost/web/src/"
});

require("js/myApp"); // Error: Module name 'js/myApp' has not been loaded yet for context: _ http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `require('FILENAME')` is used for *loading already loaded files*...i don't know what's the purpose behind it. You should use:

```
require(['module'], function(mod) {
    ... do some work ...

    // later, maybe if you want this (although, i don't understand why)
    require('module', function(m) {
        ... do some work with m - the new (or old?) module!
    })
});
```